# Passing socket data to express middleware routes

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am using express.js and socket.io. I have them set up in `./app.js`. My routes in `app.js` are set up like:

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var userRouter = require('./routes/user');

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/user', userRouter);
```

and `socket.io` in `app.js`

```
let io = socketio(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    let clients = Object.keys(io.engine.clients);

})
```

how could I pass the `clients` variable to the `userRouter`?

Answer (score 0):

Use registry object and factories:

```
const manager = {clients: []};

userRouterFactory(socketManager) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        // indexRouter code
        res.json(socketManager.clients); // Example of client variable usage
    };
}

socketFactory(socketManager) {
    return function(socket) {
        socketManager.clients = Object.keys(io.engine.clients);
    };
}

app.use(userRouterFactory(manager));

io.on('connection', socketFactory(manager));
```

Comment: Fixed userRouterFactory name and usage example it should clarify my answer. This code will allow you to update clients on connection/disconnection and provides link to clients list for router middleware.

Comment: You're not answering my question `how could I pass the clients variable to the userRouter?` The reason I state this is because `let clients = Object.keys(io.engine.clients);` is just an example of data I might want to pass into the router.

Comment: You could share the state using common accessible variable manager object which you pass to router and socket factories. You can define anything instead of `socketManager.clients`. If it's not what you want, you should to clarify your question.